# Set textbox text to 'Yes' or 'No' based on boolean property within a DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, datagridtextcolumn

I have a datagrid and one of my column is like below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue}" Header="YesOrNo" HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource MyHeaderStyle}" Width="auto">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3 5"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="No"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

What I am trying to do is to put 'Yes' or 'No' in the column for that row when BoolPropertyValue is true or false respectively.

BoolPropertyValue is a boolean property.

Unfortunately this is not working, it always puts 'True' or 'False'.

I would like to do this without the need of a converter and only using xaml code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would use an `IValueConverter` for this instead of triggers.

Comment: could you put a snippet code with IValueConverter?

Comment: typing it up now

Comment: Remove Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue}" from DataGridTextColumn and leave it only on the DataTrigger

Answer (score 2):

I would use an `IValueConverter` instead of triggers (this *can* be done with triggers if you really want to, it's a personal preference):

BoolToYesNoConverter.cs:

```
public class BoolToYesNoConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "Yes" : "No";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYesNoConverter}}" Header="YesOrNo" HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource MyHeaderStyle}" Width="auto">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3 5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Somewhere in a resource (probably in `App.xaml`):

```
<local:BoolToYesNoConverter x:key="BoolToYesNoConverter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can modify the cell template...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="YesOrNo" HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource MyHeaderStyle}" Width="auto">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3 5"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolPropertyValue}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn >
```